# how to draw text and rectangle at OpenCV cv::cuda::GpuMat or cv::ogl::Buffer image object?

Tags: opencv, gpu

I'm work for a program, plan to do this:

1.decode rtsp streams by ffmpeg and NVDEC library.

2.Wraping decoded cuda YUV_NV12 frame buffer pointer with cv::cuda::GpuMat.

3.pre-process YUV_NV12 GpuMat to normalized CV_32FC3 GpuMat and call caffe inference with new GpuMat. get deep learning results such as target rects and typeid.

4.draw target rects and type_name at YUV_NV12 GpuMat .

5.use ffmpeg and NVENC to encode drawn frame and push rtsp stream to server. so clients can perview algorithm result.

Now I was blocking in setp 4.

a) I try to avoid the draw operator, but if I send algorithm results to client instead of draw target rects and type_name at YUV_NV12 GpuMat immediately， there may have some time match work between algorithm result and video frames. I have no idea about how to make the link between rtsp frames and algorithm result packages.

b) I try to call cv::putText cv::rectangle directly with cv::cuda::GpuMat, it is not implemented now, cause OpenCV crash.

c) I try to render with cv::ogl support. I don't want to create a openGL window, but render a buffer or texture map from cuda buffer at background. As test code below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/opengl.hpp>

int main() {
    cv::Mat cpuImg;
    cv::ogl::Buffer glBuf(480,640,CV_8UC3, cv::ogl::Buffer::Target::PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, true);

    auto gpuMat = glBuf.mapDevice();
    // Do some caffe Algorithm
    glBuf.unmapDevice();

    cv::putText(glBuf, "TEST",cv::Point(20,20), cv::FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, cv::Scalar(255,255,0));

    gpuMat = glBuf.mapDevice();
    gpuMat.download(cpuImg);
    glBuf.unmapDevice();

    cv::imshow("test2",cpuImg);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

The code crash at glBuf's Constructor. Debug found glGenBuffers return GLuint bufid 0. OpenCV Assertion failed. I guess there lose some OpenGL initialize code. I don't know if

- cv::putText work correctly with cv::ogl::Buffer.
- how to make cv::ogl::Buffer work correctly.

d) As I have a decoded frame in GPU, Is there some other easy way to draw text at the image, avoid memcpy between GPU and CPU, and two different buffer in GPU?

thanks for your help